# onmouseout not triggering but onmouseover is

Tags: javascript, onmouseout

[Here is a simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/)

I have a table with sub-groupings inside of it.  I want these sub-groupings to be hidden until the user clicks the sub-header row, which looks like this:

```
<tr class="title" name="titleGroup"  
 onmouseover='this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace("---","+++");'  
 onmouseout='this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace("+++","---");'  
 onclick="$('.Group').toggle();">
    <td colspan="2">--- Group ---</td>
</tr>
```

So, `onmouseover`, should change the row to look like: +++ Group +++
and `onmouseout` should change it back to: --- Group ---

However, only the `onmouseover` triggers and I cannot get the text to go back.

I initially had the mouse over/out calling a function, but that has the same result.  Also note that this page is dynamically generated so the text is not always "Group".

What am I doing wrong and how can I get `onmouseout` to reset the text?

Comment: That's one way *not* to do it! If you're using jQuery why not use proper event handlers instead of that crap ?

Comment: @adeneo Originally it was a bit more sophisticated but it continued to not work so I kept eliminating middle pieces until this is what was left.

Comment: @XIII: You're setting the `.innerHTML` of a `tr` element to text? A `tr` should have `th` or `td` elements.

Comment: @cookiemonster I am setting the `innerHTML` to itself, just replacing all instances of "+++" with "---" and vice-versa

Comment: Yes, you are. Missed that. Whether you use jQuery or not, it sure is cleaner to have the code in a function that you execute.

Comment: @cookiemonster There used to be a function but to make absolutely sure the function was not the issue it was removed.

Comment: Do it the proper way -> http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/26/

Comment: @adeneo FYI, you removed the click functionality, but I got it working.  Thanks.

Comment: @XIII: It seems to be a bug specific to `.innerHTML` manipulation. If you edit DOM nodes instead of serializing and replacing them, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/28/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to use onmouseleave event? :)

The proper use of replace function in your case and onmouseleave event:

```
<table width="550px">
<tr class="title" name="titleGroup" >
        <td 
        onmouseover='this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace(/-{3}/g,"+");'    
        onmouseleave='this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace(/\+{3}/g,"-");' 
        onclick="$('.Group').toggle();" 
        colspan="2">--- Group ---</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Group" style="display:none;">
        <td>
<b>Group</b>
HCS:</td>
    <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="did4" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="Group" style="display:none;">
            <td>
    <b>Group</b>
NCD:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="did5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

Firefox doesn't support onmouseleave event on TR marks! Move those events deffinition to 
<td>

Comment: I changed the fiddle to use `onmouseleave` and it does not change back: http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/9/

Comment: Copy-Paste your code into the fiddle, still does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/14/

Comment: Works for me every single time... Can anyone else confirm that this doesn't work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48606/discussion-between-mr-tk-and-xiii)

Comment: Doesn't work. The `mouseout` or `mouseleave` events don't fire. I'm testing in Firefox. Works fine when it's a simple `console.log("foo");`, but doesn't work if the `mouseenter` is replacing `.innerHTML` but the `mouseleave` is `console.log()`, so it seems to have something to do with the `.innerHTML` manipulation.

Comment: @XII jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/14 - this fiddle example works like you expected

Comment: @melvas Not in Firefox it isn't

Comment: Solution added :) Goddamned browsers. :) Moving events definitions from <tr> to <td> "clears the air"! :D

Comment: Great edit.  Works well now.  Only issue I would have is your regex.  I specifically was looking for 3 in a row (`[-]{3}` and `[+]{3}`) since there could be a hyphen in the text.

Comment: Thats the answer you are looking for: /-{3}/g   and /\+{3}/g
Just check under many browsers!!! Just kidding! :)

Comment: Firefox does support `onmouseleave` on `tr`. This is a bug specific to doing `.innerHTML` replacement. And if you're going to use `onmouseleave`, then you should probably change the other to `onmouseenter` so that they're sensibly paired according to their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/30/

This works (at least in webkit browsers, Firefox still to be done)

```
onmouseover='this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace(/-/g,"+");'     
onmouseleave='this.innerHTML=this.innerHTML.replace(/\+/g,"-");'
```

It contains 2 issues:

a) replace() will replace only 1x, unless you hand over a regular expression (attention: do not surround the regex by quotes!) More about replace() can be found at http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/replace [DevDocs.io JS replace()](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/replace)

b) mouse over seems to be called, but mouseout just 1x,so only 1 time +++ will be replaced

Comment: you are right, doesn't work in FF, but does in webkit browsers. I'll check this.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of adeneo's fiddle, using jQuery with `mouseleave` is the way to go.  However, the text could include a - or + so I had to update a bit to specifically look for 3 in a row.

Here is the final jQuery:

```
$('.title').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('td', this).text(function(_,txt) {
            return txt.replace(/[+]{3}|[-]{3}/g, function(x) {
            return x=='---' ? '+++' : '---';
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/29/

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch to CSS3 (pseudo elements like :after are supported by all major browser version) or do you need to stick on js?
take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/31/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="title" name="titleGroup" style="background: #c3c3c3" onclick="$('.Group').toggle();">
        <td colspan="2">Group with CSS3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.title td {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
td:before{
    content: '+++ ';
}
td:after{
    content: ' +++';
}
tr:hover td:before{
    content: '--- ';
}
tr:hover td:after{
    content: ' ---';
}
```